# Download video and play on repeat

Tags: video, streaming

I have got a Raspberry Pi 3 connected to a monitor and connected to the WiFi. Now I have a video hosted on my server, and I want the Raspberry Pi to automatically download the video (if not downloaded yet) and play it on repeat.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give any details as to what format the video file is and what type of server you host the video file on, but if the server supports HTTP you should be able to do the following:

```
wget http://servername/videofile.xyz
mplayer -loop 0 videofile.xyz
```

`-loop 0` tells `mplayer` to loop the video forever.  You can `apt-get install` both `wget` and `mplayer` if they aren't already installed.

Comment: This looks good. I will test this out asap. Thanks!

Comment: A small improvement. The OP asked " to automatically download the video (if not downloaded yet)". Using wget's N flag will only download if file is newer: wget -N http://servername/videofile.xyz